# How can I vastly improve the perfomance in loading multiple interlinked things from Database?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, observablecollection

So, I think there MUST be a better way of doing what I am Doing...

I currently have 1 class, called "Hero". This contains 19 properties (subject to change, of course). It represents a database table I have of information.

Then, I have another Database table for comments on these hero's. One of the properties on each Hero is an ObservableCollection, and comment just contains a few basic properties.

I plan in the future as I build this up to have other relating tables attached also.

In the ViewModel, I have an ObservableCollection which I initialise with each hero from my SQLite DB.

When the program launches, I go through the following:

First, I query the Heroes Table, and pull out all the heroes into an ObservableCollection in the VM. Example:

```
DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Heroes");
foreach (DataRow Row in dt.Rows)
{
    Heroes.Add(new Hero(
        HID: Convert.ToInt32(Row["ID"]),
        HName: Row["Name"].ToString(),
        ETC.....
        ));
}
```

Then, I do the exact same for the Heroes_Comments table - I pull out everything from there, and store it in an ObservableCollection. Same way as above, only query is "SELECT * FROM Heroes_Comments", and different fields used ETC ofc.

Finally, I run a foreach on each comment in the ObservableCollection, and add it to the Hero Collection. As so:

```
foreach (Comment c in HeroesDBComments)
{
    HeroesDBHeroes.Single(h => h.ID == c.Foreign).Comments.Add(c);
}
```

It all works, and does its job etc... However with not that much test data, it does seem to take a fair while to do everything and I feel that as I add more things to this it will bog down completely and be worthless.

What can I do to improve this? I would rather get it right now, than have to improve and fix it all later on. :)

(FYI - Test data is currently looking at about 10 Hero's and 5 Comments, all 5 comments on the same Hero. Each Hero does have 2 images stored as a BLOB... so thats not the smallest amount of data ever but I feel as though the foreach on the comments is bad when it comes to adding more linked tables and doing the same with those... I just dont know anyhting better?)

Thought: Are ObservableCollections slower and there is a better alternative perhaps?

Comment: Why load all of them? Maybe just load the hero names, and then when the user goes into more detail, load specifics for that record. It really depends on how you are displaying this all to the user, but there isn't a reason to load any more data than the user can look at.

Comment: All the data is presented in a datagrid. Most things along the main row, some thigns in the rowdetails. There will be other base classes similar to Hero when this is complete, all with additionals, But if I dont load at startup, the first time the user accesses the page with the datatable (which will be all they would ever be doing really) it would load everything then if I wanted to not load until they need it... but it looks worse to click a button and not see anything happen for ages then a longer loading time at start.

Comment: How many rows can the user see at once? You can just load the visible rows, and then in the background preload the next set of visible rows as the user scrolls down. I can't imagine they can see and interpret all this data at once, you must have a way for them to expand details on a hero or something.

Comment: I hold some information in rowdetails... (All of the things attached to each hero is held here for example). So EG, comments on hero are not visible until user clicks the row. So should I only add the comments to the Hero when the row is clicked? I dont know how that would work really.. Listening for a row to be selected, then adding all comments matching that hero ID to that hero, this would refresh the Datagrid, would that result in the datagrid not expanding the row then? I dont know how it would behave...

Answer (score 0):

You're burning a lot of cycles just doing network round trips--much more than you realize.

I'd say don't be afraid of SQL joins. You will almost certainly get much better overall performance if you craft a SQL query which pulls all of the data back in one call. Order the data by "Hero," then by whatever matters in the comments table. As you iterate over the result set, just check for a change in the Hero id so you know when the context changes. Yes, you'll pull some redundant data, but overall performance will likely improve drastically.

Are you using connection pooling? Are you making all of these calls on the same connection or spinning up a new connection each time.

It's also possible (probable) that you're pulling more data than you're using, with the `select * from ...` queries, and whatever efficiencies you're gaining to making multiple requests to the database are more than swallowed up in the overhead of pulling more columns than you need *and* reconnecting over and over.

Alternatively, pull the heroes, pull out just the id values then pull all of the comments for all of the Heros in one additional call. Use multithreading so that you can start populating your data structure at the same time that you're pulling the comment data.